# Wordpress dynamic image slider plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and I am looking for special type of image slider.
The image slider is such that when the image slides the contents of the image comes after words from different sides and also goes out in the similar way and the next slides comes.
I have seen it on many websites and do not know how to make it and what is a suitable plugin for it.
The one similar image slider on one site is:
https://www.eziline.com or http://www.qsoft.co/pakistan.
 Also tell me how can I search this type of slider on internet i.e. what is the name of these types of slider.

Answer (score 1):

https://revolution.themepunch.com/ is one that can mostly do what you're looking for. Note that the example you gave is much more complex than just a slider. While I was working at a motorcycle shop, I did their site with Slider Revolution. It's not the most amazing site, but you can get an idea of some things that Slider Revolution can do. https://combustioncycles.com

Comment: Yes I know that it is a complex slider and it is a difficult task for me to do such type of work therefore here is a simple example and can you tell me how to make this type of slider.http://www.qsoft.co/pakistan/

Comment: When you use Chrome browsers "Inspect" or view page source it shows that that site uses Revolution Sliver v2.2.

Comment: Revolution slider I have searched is an expensive option for me as I have just started wordpress development therefore I am looking for free plugin. Can you help me in this case.